# Data Visualization tools - Opensource or licensed?

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

We have been using Power BI and Qlikview/Qliksense for a while. But despite the best efforts of the Digital/IT team, we are not able to get users to do data visualisation on their own. So the Digital team has to maintain a consistent headcount for data visualisation. This is over and above the fees for proprietary software. In this scenario, looks like it be cheaper to use opensource. 
So, which tool would you recommend? My request is for a tool that can do all the basic functions of PowerBi/Qlik but be open source. I have a team of programmers to maintain the tool.

Any suggestions are welcome...

Comment: Please remove any reference to PowerBi/Qlik and instead explain all of the features you need (ETL? cubes? MDX? drilldown web interface? dashboards? export? etc). The question must be understandable by people who have never used PowerBI (=most BI experts). Also, should it be easy enough for business people to create their own visualizations, or are you giving up on that point? Please edit your question then ask us to reopen, thanks!